# Can I use the globe plugin on a Windows OS and where can I find the plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, windows, globe

I am trying to add my layers (health facilities and pertinent infrastructure within a region) to a 3D image of the landscape and someone recommended I use the Globe plugin. I can not find the Globe plugin. Does anyone know where I can find it?/ Will the plugin work for a Windows OS?

Comment: Re your title: [QGIS accepts donations](http://www.qgis.org/en/sponsorship.html).  That would be one way to fund a plugin.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

As of QGIS 2.16, Globe now works on Windows as well, see:

[image]

The plugin is installed by default. It only needs to be activated in the plugin manager.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://sourcepole.ch/the-state-of-qgis-globe:

> The bad news is, that the globe plugin is not working on Windows with OSGeo4W. It seems that one of the OSGeo4W libraries (GDAL?) is compiled with an incompatible MS compiler version.

So the answer is: No.

For other OS, you have to compile it for yourself, or wait until the plugin has entered a stable status. Look out for news here:

http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Globe_Plugin